# Do the vk::BufferUsageFlags have a significant impact on performance?

Tags: c++, performance, vulkan

When creating a buffer, you need to specify its usage through `vk::BufferUsageFlags`, specifying if it will be used as a vertex, index, transfer... etc buffer.

Due to convenience, it is extremely tempting to enable the most commonly used subset whenever you make one of these buffers. e.g. have the vertex, index and storage flags enabled all the time.

For desktop applications, does this have  a major effect in performance?

Comment: I don't quite see what's convenient about giving wrong information. You seem to be looking for an "OK" to be lazy (no offense intended)...? Such practices can backfire, now or later, similar to ignoring compiler warnings because "it works". Is there really a problem actually giving the *correct* flags only?

Comment: It's an RHI issue. If you can use multiple flags with no performance penalty you are NOT giving incorrect information, rather you are giving less information (i.e. you know it is one or the other, rather than a specific one).

If you can use multiple flags with no perforrmance penalty you can make an API that just creates the buffer, but if performance is affected then you need to allow for buffer creation hints on the user end.

One API is simpler and thus if it would provide no benefits tot he user to push that responsibility to them, there's no need to do so.

Comment: @Makogan: "*If you can use multiple flags with no perforrmance penalty you can make an API that just creates the buffer*" Vulkan was invented so that you wouldn't create APIs that "create a buffer". You create APIs that implement your rendering system. That system *uses* buffers, but the detailed nature of buffers, as well as precisely how many and which ones to create, are something that's part of the system, not exposed to external users of that system. That is, you don't have an API to "create a buffer"; you have an API that manages meshes and so forth.

Comment: Or put simply, building OpenGL on top of Vulkan is not a good way to use the API.

Comment: None of this is answering the question. @NicolBolas, sure maybe, perhaps. Yet a system that needs to abstract away multiple rendering backends, such as Unreal's RHI still needs to implement some form of "allocate buffer". That then dispatches the aproriate calls to the rendering backend. This call may or may not include buffer creation hint flags.

That is all this is about. no need to fall into the stereotype of "how do i accomplish X" "doing X is silly" that SO is often criticized for.

Comment: @Makogan Implementation-dependent. Requires knowledge of the insides of proprietary drivers. The answer would be brittle over time. Might depend what is done with the buffer in the application, including any use in extensions in the future. Cannot be authoritatively answered and so an unsuitable question for StackOverflow format.

Comment: Obligatory cheeky answer is: measure measure measure. I wouldn't expect major impact for big values of "major".

Comment: @Makogan: Yet still in the vast majority of cases "Y is silly, tell us about your actual problem X" *is the most helpful and correct answer*. Ref. [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Don't sneeze at the experience of others, it is what you cane here for.